# Using 122 key keyboards with Emacs

Tags: keyboard-layout, keyboard

Does using a 122-key keyboard make it easier to use Emacs, in relation to having more keys to bind commands to? I am thinking of the various models on offer from Unicomp specifically.

Comment: Welcome to emacs.stackexchange.com.  This forum is primarily used for questions that lead to finite answers, where just about everyone will agree the accepted answer is the definitive solution.  Questions that seek opinions are generally marked as such and are subsequently closed.  A popular Emacs forum where everybody loves to chime in and give their own opinions is https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/ .  Unless you are able to revise your question to solicit a more finite answer, it should probably be deleted or closed.

Comment: A question of whether XYZ makes Emacs "easier to use" is primarily opinion-based, which means it is not very helpful. Such questions are typically closed.